# Getting an unexpected sum with a total of 109% (instead of 100%)

Tags: sql, sqlite

My SQL is not giving the expected result. I need to estimate the percentage of use of a certain product in different countries and associate this to the supplier providing the licence for the products.

I've got table a, a list from which I'd like to get some statistic values (81000 lines).

```
CREATE TABLE "2020_csv" (
    "Date"  TEXT,
    "Server"    TEXT,
    "Feature"   TEXT,
    "User"  TEXT,
    "Host"  TEXT,
    "Hours" REAL,
    "Hours&Mins"    TEXT
);
```

then, table b, one which has an ID, a TLA, some location information and a supplier ID. The TLA contains a country code.

```
CREATE TABLE "Locations" (
"id"    INTEGER,
"TLA"   TEXT,
"Name"  TEXT,
"NameIT"    TEXT,
"CountryCode"   TEXT,
"Country"   TEXT,
"State" TEXT,
"Society"   TEXT,
"UNC"   TEXT,
"conform"   INTEGER,
"SupplierID"    INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT),
FOREIGN KEY("SupplierID") REFERENCES "Locations"("id")
);
```

finally table c, the supplier list

```
CREATE TABLE "Suppliers" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "name"  TEXT,
    "country"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

The hostname "Host" in table *a* contains the tla (three letter acronym) in the first three places. The qestion is, how many percentage of each usage (each line in table *a*) in hours is assigned to which supplier (table *c*)? There are entries with no supplier (*null*) and each supplier may support different locations (in b.SupplierID)

I did that (in SQLite using DB Browser for SQLite):

```
SELECT
    round(sum(a.Hours), 1) Totalhours,
    count(a.Host) UseCount, 
    round(sum(a.Hours)/count(a.Host), 1) PerUseHourAv, 
    round(sum(a.Hours)/489608.1*100, 1) Percent,
    coalesce(c.name, '-- no supplier assigned --') Supplier,
    b.TLA
FROM '2020_csv' a
LEFT JOIN 'Locations' b ON substr(a.Host, 1, 3) like b.TLA
LEFT JOIN 'Suppliers' c ON b.SupplierID = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
COLLATE NOCASE
```

In the "Percent" line in place of 489608.1, I had had a sub sql:

```
SELECT total(Hours) 'Total hours'FROM '2020_csv'
```

Which was replaced with the constant for performance reason. Unfortunately, **in the result, the sum of "Totalhours" is 536389,7 and the sum of "Percent" comes up to app. 109,6%** instead of the expected app. 100%.

I assume the some lines are counted twice but I cannot figure out my mistake. Could anybody provide a hint please?

[Result list with sums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4mKP.png)

The lower line shows the sums of the columns.

Comment: I see you using 2 LEFT JOIN, this might be a reason for duplication. try using INNER JOIN one by one and write your comment, please.

Comment: STEP 1  : replace the first LEFT JOIN by INNER JOIN
STEP2  : replace the second LEFT JOIN by INNER JOIN
STEP3  : replace both LEFT JOIN by INNER JOIN

Comment: In the `Locations` table, shouldn't it be `FOREIGN KEY("SupplierID") REFERENCES "Suppliers"("id")`, i.e. references suppliers instead of itself? If so, this would mean that there can be more than one location per supplier, this would lead to a duplication of the `2020_csv` rows in the query resulting in a higher sum than expected.

Comment: Your results show that you're dividing by 489608.1 instead of 536389,7 that's exactly what explains the 9% too high of a number.

Comment: You should divide by `536389.7`. If you decide to insert this number as constant in your query, then you must update it whenever changes are made to the table.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering so quickly. @Useme Alehosaini: The results of:

Comment: Thank you very much for answering so quickly. @Useme Alehosaini: The results of:

STEP 1: 536389,7 - 109,6%
STEP 2: 505288,7 - 103,3%
STEP 3: 502541,7 - 102,7%
It is already closer and I'll reconsider the result.

@ Pieter and Oliver:

`SELECT total(Hours) 'Total hours'FROM '2020_csv'`

gives 489608.1, not 536389,7 and it is similar, if I leave it in my sql like:

`round(sum(a.Hours)/(SELECT total(Hours) FROM '2020_csv_new')*100, 1) Percent,`

Comment: @Charly are you sure the value 489608.1 is correct? I mean are you sure the subquery is giving the right result?